# What does ‘Älteren’ mean in this sentence?

Tags: german-to-english

I am currently reading *taz.de* article "Tagebücher des Sowjet-Politikers Maiski. Versprechen und manipulieren". The article begins with the following two sentences:

> Fragen wir heute nach den Namen der wichtigsten Diplomaten der Sowjetunion, fragen wir vermutlich vergeblich. Nur wenigen würde wahrscheinlich Andrei Gromyko einfallen (Außenminister 1957–1985), den **Älteren** sein Vorgänger im Amt, Wjatscheslaw Molotow (1939–1957).

I would translate *Älteren* in this context as *Older Comrade*. But Molovov (born 1890) was actually older than Gromyko (born 1909). And based on my knowledge of the Russian history, in 1957 Molotov was far more influential than Gromyko; so, based on his prior merits, Gromyko could not have been called an Older Comrade to Molotov in 1957.

So, what's the meaning of *Älteren* in the above sentence?

Comment: Ich muss sagen, ich habe den Satz nicht auf Anhieb verstanden - Sowas sollte nicht in der Zeitung stehen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Satz liest sich in der Tat nicht sonderlich flüssig. Er ist so zu verstehen:

> Nur wenigen würde wahrscheinlich Gromyko einfallen.
>   Den Älteren würde Gromykos Vorgänger Molotow einfallen.

Es geht also um die älteren unter denen, die hier hypothetisch gefragt werden.